# using ng-model in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am having some problems with angular. Now I have a following code :

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            <input ng-change="test()" ng-model='abc'> {{abc}}
            <span>{{item.price| currency}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price * item.quantity| currency}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                    function CartController($scope) {
                        $scope.items = [
                            {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                            {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                            {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
                        ];
                        $scope.test = function() {
                            console.log($scope.abc);
                        }
                        $scope.remove = function(index) {
                            $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    }
        </script>
```

I wanna know why I can not console.log abc value in controller? My English is bad, pls help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
$scope.test = function() {
     console.log($scope.abc);
 }
```

to

```
$scope.test = function() {
     console.log(this.abc);
 }
```

"this" will resolve to the current scope object and you should be able to print the value as you keep changing the text.

Comment: @rajasur can you tell why the way he was doing was not working?

Comment: @acdcjunior, Each template instance inside ng-repeat gets its own scope (Refer http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). So what we are having inside of the ng-repeat instance is a childscope of the parent. Using "this" instead of $scope uses the childscope instead of referring to the Parent. If you inspect the variables through a debugger, you will see that the "scope" inside of the ng-repeat templates is actually the child of the parent "$scope" defined in the original code.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry I forgot :D. It's perfect answer, thanks again @rajasaur

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you declare `abc` as a variable before trying to use it?

```
function CartController($scope){
    var $scope.abc = 'foo';
    ...
```

Comment: yes, I tried to declared as you said, but when we invoke console.log($scope.abc); in the test() function and we change input value then the result always is "foo" because controller will not listen the change of input value, what do you think about that @Mee :)? Thank you for relying